# Porting of HTTP client (cURL) library on android

Tags: android, libcurl

Am working on auto provisioning in which I need to download a file.enc from the server.This I had done using cURL(other option is wget) to get it done.Now I need to compile the curl source code with agcc (ARM tool chain compile) and port the same on a Android device.
Am clueless so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`HttpGet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) provided in the android sdk?

Comment: Am using this curl in my  C code to get the file.Can I do the same with HTTPget??

Comment: Have anyone used cURL for android devices so far??

Answer (score -1):

I have documented the way to compile libcurl into your application for Android. The only challenge is to configure the libcurl for ARM architecture. You will need to tweak the compilation parameters for your environment.

http://web.archive.org/web/20110424123421/http://thoughts.seul.in/2011/01/compiling-curl-libcurl-for-android-using-ndk-on-snow-leopard-mac-os-x

Comment: Your link is dead, can you post the contents directly here in your answer?